# line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: shell-script

Running shell to string together several csv files, ran this process before the end of the year and ran fine, running today after only making the edit to include 2017 and receiving the above mentioned error.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPORTS="Product_Report"
YEARS="2014 2015 2016 2017”
MONTHS="01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12"

for r in ${REPORTS}; do
    echo "Rebuilding ${r}.csv"
    head -n 1 ${r}.header > ${r}.csv
    for y in ${YEARS}; do
        for m in ${MONTHS}; do
            f="Data/${r}_${y}${m}.csv"
            if [ ! -s "${f}" ]; then echo "Skipping ${f} (not present)"; continue; fi
            tail -n +2 ${f} >> ${r}.csv
            wc -l ${f}
        done
    done
    echo
    wc -l ${r}.csv
done
```

Comment: Try to change `YEARS="2014 2015 2016 2017”` with `YEARS="2014 2015 2016 2017"`; It could be just the `"` character that causes the problem

Comment: @Echoes_86 Having a curly quote will definitely produce an error. I bet you're right.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was wrong, I appreciate the help, just getting started with using shell so I expect I will be posting more questions along the way.

Answer (score 6):

The text editor you used to make the change used a `”` instead of the expected `"` to close the YEARS string. That messes up the complete string delimitations of the file, which you can see in the syntax highlighting of your question.

Corrected version below, note the different syntax highlighting:

```
#!/bin/bash

REPORTS="Product_Report"
YEARS="2014 2015 2016 2017"
MONTHS="01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12"

for r in ${REPORTS}; do
    echo "Rebuilding ${r}.csv"
    head -n 1 ${r}.header > ${r}.csv
    for y in ${YEARS}; do
        for m in ${MONTHS}; do
            f="Data/${r}_${y}${m}.csv"
            if [ ! -s "${f}" ]; then echo "Skipping ${f} (not present)"; continue; fi
            tail -n +2 ${f} >> ${r}.csv
            wc -l ${f}
        done
    done
    echo
    wc -l ${r}.csv
done
```